# Touch friendly screenshot shortcut

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, touchscreen, screenshot

Is there a way to get a shortcut icon to the side or top bar, that'll trigger the gnome screenshot utility, that is normally started with the print-key?

I'm using a Thinkpad Yoga convertible, so it's pretty uncomfortable to fold the keyboard back just to press the print button. Accessing the screenshot utility through the search is also annoying.

edit:
**Solution found:**

I've got a pretty unconvential solution.
I "just" wrote my own gnome extension using `gnome-extensions create --interactive`
The example extension adds a button to the panel. I just had to add the command `Main.screenshotUI.open()`

Full edited code of the `Indicator` class of the example

```javascript
const Indicator = GObject.registerClass(
class Indicator extends PanelMenu.Button {
    _init() {
        super._init(0.0, _('My Shiny Indicator'));

        this.add_child(new St.Icon({
            icon_name: 'face-smile-symbolic',
            style_class: 'system-status-icon',
        }));

        let item = new PopupMenu.PopupMenuItem(_('Show Notification'));
        item.connect('activate', () => {
            Main.screenshotUI.open()
        });
        this.menu.addMenuItem(item);
    }
});
```

Maybe a bit of the "crack a nut with a sledgehammer" approach, but I see a lot of possible features I could add to make it touch-friendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this in my opinion is to install a separate application and add it to the launcher. Shotwell, Flameshot or scrot are all great simple screenshot tools, which could be pinned to the launcher.

Comment: Thank you! I have to admit that i just got pretty used to the build in tool.

I've found another solution and edited my original post.

Comment: Hah That's one way to do it. you should post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to have an answer:

I "just" wrote my own gnome extension using `gnome-extensions create --interactive`
The example extension adds a button to the panel. I just had to add the command `Main.screenshotUI.open()`

Full edited code of the `Indicator` class of the example

```javascript
const Indicator = GObject.registerClass(
class Indicator extends PanelMenu.Button {
    _init() {
        super._init(0.0, _('My Shiny Indicator'));

        this.add_child(new St.Icon({
            icon_name: 'face-smile-symbolic',
            style_class: 'system-status-icon',
        }));

        let item = new PopupMenu.PopupMenuItem(_('Show Notification'));
        item.connect('activate', () => {
            Main.screenshotUI.open()
        });
        this.menu.addMenuItem(item);
    }
});
```

Maybe a bit of the "crack a nut with a sledgehammer" approach, but I see a lot of possible features I could add to make it touch-friendly.